# Send random data in java

Tags: java, tcp, udp, datagram, mtu

I'm doing a project for the university. The application that I´m doing is a UDP and TCP Client/Server in Java and we have to measure the time that takes send some data. The question that I have, is the following one:

To make the app faster, I would like to know if there is any way to send random data in a buffer, I mean, I do not want to use one of my files in my computer, I just want to send for example 500 bytes of data, but I do not mind what. I know you can to do it from the terminal in Linux directly, or with Iperf, but I do not know how to implement that in my Java app.

Comment: In Java, you can use the class `Random` to generate random bytes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the first question, having no idea about MTU and MSS.

To create random data and send it, you simply have to use the following:

```
Random random = new Random();
byte[] data = new byte[500];
random.nextBytes(data); // fill with data
try (OutputStream out = ...) {
  out.write(data);
}
```